# gstreamer saved files have no audio

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to use this command to create multiple files from stream but they have no audio playback, I think decodebin should be dealing with it, what am I doing wrong?

`gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=video.mp4 ! queue ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! queue ! timeoverlay ! x264enc key-int-max=10 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=videos/test%02d.mp4 max-size-time=1000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you make that assumption that `decodebin` will handle it? `decodebin` will decode the audio track to raw audio and exposes an audio pad. If you don't make use of that pad it will not make itself into the file.

Since you transcode you will have to re-encode the audio too:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=video.mp4 ! queue ! decodebin ! queue ! \
videoconvert ! queue ! timeoverlay ! x264enc key-int-max=10 ! h264parse ! \
splitmuxsink location=videos/test%02d.mp4 max-size-time=1000000000000 \
decodebin0. ! queue ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! splitmuxsink0.
```

If you don't want to re-encode but passthrough the audio `decodebin` is the wrong way. `parsebin` may be a better fit in that case.